# OfficeScript SelectedTable.deleteRowsAt error in Excel desktop

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I am trying to delete a set of rows within a Table using office script as part of converting VBA scripts to Office Script
I need the office script to run Online as well as Desktop

So this is the script I have

```
let SelectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("1. N12");
let SelectedTable = SelectedSheet.getTable("Table_N12");
let RowCount = SelectedTable.getRowCount();
SelectedTable.deleteRowsAt(5, RowCount - 5)
```

While this works fine in Excel online, If i download the excel file and try to run, it gives me an error

> ExcelScript.Table.deleteRowsAt is not supported in this version of
> Excel.(Office Scripts Error).

So what other options do I have for deleting a set of rows in Desktop excel

Regards
Nisha

I tried with SelectedTable.resize, but doesnt seem to work. I got an error

```
Line 14: Table resize: This range won't work because it doesn't align with the existing table. The table requires headers to remain in the same row and include at least one row of data, and the new range should overlap the existing table.
```

Comment: OfficeScripts is a cloud based service so how are you even getting that error?  i.e. how do you try and trigger the script from your desktop application?

Comment: @Skin Office Scripts is now supported on both Windows and Mac versions of Excel https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/what-s-new-in-excel-october-2022/ba-p/3646198

Comment: Well there you go! @BrianGonzalez that’s mad news.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug on our end - we're currently investigating and I can update you once we have an idea of what's going on. Thank you and happy holidays Nisha!

Warmly,
Nancy from the Office Scripts team

Comment: The bug fix should be in the latest set of updates to the Code Editor - please feel free to check back over the next few days and let us know if you're still seeing this error. Thanks!

Comment: The script is working now, Thanks Nancy.